# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException when trying to get a drawable image

Tags: android, sqlite, android-drawable, listadapter, android-imagebutton

i searched the web and this site in particular, but i haven't found an answer to my problem yet.

My aim: I have a ListView with some elements, one is an ImageButton. I want to set the Image of this Button dynamically, based on data i have stored in the local SQLite Database.

Here are the code snippets:

**Saving the Drawable Image in the database:**

```
e.setBild(R.drawable.goal_icon);
```

as you can see, i save it as an integer. From what i've read, that's the way to go.

**Using the Image:**

I think the more important part is, how i try to get the Drawable Image. This is the part of my Adapter i use to fill the ListView:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                getContext().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_actions, null);
    }

    ImageButton icon = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    try{
        icon.setImageResource(getItem(position).getBild());
    }catch(Exception e){
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_icon);

    }
```

The 'getBild' method gets an integer (obviously).

He allways goes to catch and gives me the default_icon. 
Here is the Stacktrace:

```
09-12 12:22:19.636  23635-23635/android.ht.sportstatistik W/ResourceType﹕ No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000002
09-12 12:22:19.637  23635-23635/android.ht.sportstatistik W/ImageView﹕ Unable to find resource: 2
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x2
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1307)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:826)
        at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:403)
        at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:747)
        at android.widget.ImageView.onMeasure(ImageView.java:874)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:698)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:482)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureScrapChild(ListView.java:1207)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1272)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:851)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2618)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2019)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1177)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1383)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1065)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5901)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.in
```

Am i missing something? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what does this funtion return icon.setImageResource(getItem(position).getBild());

Comment: I think you are asking android to get a resource that is not in R file/ not in your apk.

Comment: does `getItem(position).getBild()` returns int resource id or some int value? I'm pretty sure that second ... so what's you expected?

Comment: well, with     setBild(R.drawable.goal_icon); i should save it as an resource id, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the Android developer documentation specified [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int))

The integer value in the setImageresource() must be a resource id from R.java file.

Looking at your code and the issue, it seems that you are passing your own values in the id parameter of the method.

I know that you are setting proper value in the method, but somehow it is stored as something else and what you get as an image resource is "2".
Now when you open the R.java file, you may not find any entry corresponding to this value.

A better approach would be to copy the files in the sdcard and then fetching the Bitmap and then displaying it the imageview using setImageBitmap() method.

Hope this helps you to identify the issue.